# Assertion error on ZeroMQ Majordomo worker

Tags: c++, zeromq, domo

I got a problem with the ZeroMQ Majordomo worker API, which fails on an assertion, using this simple worker, client.

The broker I am using is all from the example section from ZeroMQ site.  What's the **`m_reply_to`** used for and when is it set?

```
mdwrkapi.hpp:123: zmsg* mdwrk::recv(zmsg*&): Assertion `m_reply_to.size()!=0' failed.
```

Here is the worker code.

```
  mdwrk session ("tcp://localhost:5555", "GenericData", verbose);

zmsg *reply = 0;
    while (1) {
        zmsg *request = session.recv (reply);
        if (request == 0) {
            break;              //  Worker was interrupted
        }
        reply = request;        //  Echo is complex… :-)
    }
```

And here is the client part:

```
mdcli session ("tcp://localhost:5555", verbose);
int count = 1;
while(1) {
    zmsg * request = new zmsg("Hello world");
    zmsg * reply = session.send ("GenericData", request);

    if (reply) {
        delete reply;
    } else {
        continue;              //  Interrupt or failure
        puts("Interupt or failure");
    }
    sleep(1);
    puts("sleeping");
}
```

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ code!

Comment: thanks olaf for noticing that.

Answer (score 1):

### What's the **`m_reply_to`** used for?

As taken from the Majordomo source code, **`m_reply_to`** is declared as:

```
/*  =====================================================================
mdwrkapi.hpp

Majordomo Protocol Worker API
Implements the MDP/Worker spec at http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:7.

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Copyright (c) 1991-2011 iMatix Corporation <www.imatix.com>
...
*/
...
private:
    ...
    //  Return address, if any
    std::string m_reply_to;  // <<------------------------- RETURN ADDRESS
```

and serves for storing a return address like here, in `recv()`:

```
                //  We should pop and save as many addresses as there are
                //  up to a null part, but for now, just save one...
                m_reply_to = msg->unwrap ();
```

---

### When it is set?

As taken from the source code, it may happen inside a `recv()`:

```
//  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Send reply, if any, to broker and wait for next request.

zmsg *
recv (zmsg *&reply_p)
{
    //  Format and send the reply if we were provided one
    zmsg *reply = reply_p;
    assert (reply || !m_expect_reply);
    if (reply) {
        assert (m_reply_to.size()!=0);
        ...
```